# CASE WHEN ... ELSE LIKE

Tags: sql, oracle

I need to use a like when a Parameter is null. It's been a long day and I need an extra pair of eyes.

Currently I have a parameter in SSRS so that I can search a staff member, this works perfectly fine. However I would like to add a NULL parameter in Report Builder (which I can do, it's the SQL I can't do for some reason today).

```
Where
   case 
     when  :P_Lecturer is not null then coalesce(to_char(s_details.person_code), 'No Staff Attached') in (:P_Lecturer)
   else coalesce(to_char(s_details.person_code), 'No Staff Attached') like '%%'
end
and [Rest of Conditions]
```

I am getting the error "missing keyword". What am I missing?

Is there any better way of doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CASE doesn't really work for what you're trying to do. But OR works fine. You just need to get your parens right

```
WHERE
(
   ( :P_Lecturer is not null AND 
      coalesce(to_char(s_details.person_code), 'No Staff Attached') in (:P_Lecturer) 
   )
       OR
   ( :P_Lecturer is null  AND 
      coalesce(to_char(s_details.person_code), 'No Staff Attached') like '%%'
   )
)
and [Rest of Conditions]
```